# class method call freezing UI

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm currently trying to solve the freezing of my UI on a certain page in my application. I've tracked the issue down to my class method called `handleRequire` which basically calls 3 action creators who each do some calculations and then calling an api to fetch the correct data.

I am 100% sure the UI frezze is not because of unwanted re-renders in components or calling selectors (tested all components used on this page).

What you see below is the issue namely I select a large period but then the UI freezes and the datepicker is also not hidden (as it normally does).

**The issue**
[image]

Notice that the following warning is printed in the console: `[Violation] 'click' handler took 1414ms`. This `click` handler is on the datepicker component which handles the visibility of the dropdown.

**Page class [(full component gist)](https://gist.github.com/nealoke/3ebb968bdad22bd9aeb1ff725c111660#file-page-js)**

```
class Overview extends PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.handleRequire = this.handleRequire.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.handleRequire();
    }

    handleRequire() {
        const { requireAccountDayStats, requireQuestions, requireQuestionsDayStats } = this.props;

        requireQuestions()
            .then(() => requireAccountDayStats())
            .then(() => requireQuestionsDayStats());
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <DatePicker onChange={this.handleRequire} />
                // ... stuff
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**DatePicker call [(full gist)](https://gist.github.com/nealoke/3ebb968bdad22bd9aeb1ff725c111660#file-datepicker-js)**

```
handleChange(...) {
    // ... stuff

    this.setState(
        { 
            // stuff 
        },
        () => onChange(newValue)) // Is this the issue as it might wait for the onChange function to be fully finished before re-rendering?
    );
}
```

[`requireAccountDayStats() requireQuestionsDayStats()`](https://gist.github.com/nealoke/3ebb968bdad22bd9aeb1ff725c111660#file-requirequestionsdaystats-js)

**Question**

I guess my question is on how to let the `handleRequire()` class method run while not interfering with the UI?

Comment: Do requireAccountDayStats() and requireQuestionsDayStats() methods perform network calls?

Comment: @SajithDilshan yes they do, also see the updated question for how the ´onChange´ prop is used as I think it could be the issue as well

Comment: Could you please post the complete code of the component? It is hard to figure out where the issue is with the posted code.

Comment: @SajithDilshan do you mean the datepicker component or the page component?

Comment: If possible both components

Comment: @SajithDilshan added them as gist links in question, thanks for helping!

Comment: Seems like handleChange() method is invoked for all date changes and in return onChange() is invoked multiple times. Make sure you are making non-blocking network calls and if possible restrict all the network calls into componentDidMount() method. if possible can you post the method body of equireAccountDayStats() and requireQuestionsDayStats()  methods as well. I guess these two are the culprits.

Comment: @SajithDilshan I have added them to the gist as well. I tested but the `handleChange()` method only get's fired once when changing the period